# Are stuff inside an ASP.NET .resx "static?"

Tags: asp.net, session, resx

In ASP.NET, can I store *parameterized* sql queries in .resx files and not get into trouble when I have several users logged in at the same time?

For example, i'll put my user detail query in a .resx file:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

How will ASP.NET treat it? Like a "Session" (different users have different results) or like a "public static"/"Application" ?

Comment: guys, for the specifics: I already created Methods to "run" sql queries (with or without parameters), I **can't** use SP's nor LINQ (MySql 4), I have about *80* sql queries.

Answer (score 2):

resource files are typically for storing language specific strings, not for storing queries to execute, I guess you could do it, but why?  It seems that there is a piece missing from your question, what is driving this requirement on your end?

EDIT: If you only have access to mysql, why not use an ORM tool like [subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) or [nhibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not intending to comment so much on whether this is a good idea or not, but basically, aren't you just storing strings?  When you use a parameterized query, in ADO.NET at least, you will add the parameters before running the query.

Answer (score 1):

`@UserID` would have to come from your code, which needs to somehow obtain the value from the logged-in user (or however your app works), so it doesn't matter how static or not the strings are.

That said, you should be using stored procedures if possible instead of this.

Comment: There are occasionally reasons to not use stored procedures.

Comment: I'd love to use SP's but sadly, the DB (which i don't own) does not support it (MySql 4)

Comment: Ah, OK. I won't be snarky and recommend you get a real DB then :D Still, this will work, I suppose. Better stored inside a resource file than inline in code.

Comment: hey i'm updated my answer to inclue links to some better solutions.